# iphone application automatic start up

Tags: iphone

is there any option in iphone so that i can start my application automatically within a predefined time interval ? For example like alarm application but we don't want our application to run in the background. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

There is not option like this. The best you can implement is local notification which is displayed to the user and then application can be launch via the notification.
Check out [About Local Notifications and Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) to know how it works and eventually implement it

Answer (score 4):

**No.** There is no way to start your application automatically.

You can give user option to start your application using [Local notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) though it does not guarantee your application would be started because if user ignores local notification than your application will not launched.

Answer (score 2):

There is no officially supported way to do this.